# Error when trying to pass a variable to a second view

Tags: swift, data-binding, swiftui

In the following code I have a struct that has different values.

```
struct Workout: Codable {
let exercise: [Exercise]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case exercise = "exercise"
 }
}

struct Exercise: Codable {
   let exercise, set: Int
}


class WorkoutViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var workout: Workout
   init(_ workout: Workout) {
     self.workout = workout
   }
}
```

In my main view I call initialise the value as this:

```
struct CreateWorkoutView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myExercises = WorkoutViewModel(Workout(exercise: [Exercise(exercise: 1, set: 1)]))

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(
        destination: View2(exerciseList: self.$myExercises.workout.exercise)
    ){
        Text("Add Exercises")
    }
}


struct View2: View {
    @ObservedObject var excersices = getExercisesData()
    @Binding var exerciseList: [Exercise]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(excersices.datas){i in
                HStack{
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(i.name)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    }

                }.onTapGesture {
                    self.exerciseList.append(Exercise(exercise: i.exerciseId, set: 1))
                }
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

There is a problem with the line where I set self.$myExercises.workout.exercise. The XCode error shows a different location (a `HStack`) and gives the following error as it seems unrelated:
`Generic parameter 'C0' could not be inferred` Info: `1. In call to function 'buildBlock' (SwiftUI.ViewBuilder)`

I want to move this the exercise array to the next view to add items to it.

any idea why the above part of the cone is not allowed?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the minimally reproducible code for `View2`

Comment: @NewDev Sure. I just updated my post.

Comment: Do you want the new added items from the second view to be in the previous view?

Comment: @Danny - where? You added `ExerciseListView`, but the destination of the NavigationLink is `View2`. Are they the same?

Comment: @NewDev Sorry I forgot to change the name of the view. `View2` is the same as `ExerciseListView `. I just updated it

Comment: @BenO Yes `View1` will hold the main struct and its information will be made from different sub views. but 'View1' should be able to have the data.

Comment: Since we don't have `getExercisesData`, I removed it and substituted references to it with some constants, and it works (there's also a missing `}` in `CreateWorkoutView`. So, I don't think the bug is in the code you posted (i.e. not reproducible)

Answer (score 0):

The error message was unrelated. The problem was that the `let exercise, set: Int` was a constant and not a var. changing that solved the issue.
Commenting the part the error raised sometimes help to understand what the compiler  is really complaining about.